# How to get a specific line from command output in batch script into a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, perforce

I'd like to get a changelist description from perforce, which involves calling a p4 describe -s , so the ouput would be as below. Is there a way to get  (trimmed characters from the third line) from the output just using windows batch syntax?

```
Change 6582 by username on 2016/12/06 00:35:41

        MyChangeDescription

Affected files ...

... //depot/foo.txt#7 edit
... //depot/foo2.txt#6 edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %Description% change -o 6582
```

Comment: this did the trick, and made my need to read multiple lines obsolete, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40986156.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqskip=2tokens=*" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "desc=%%a"
 GOTO show
)

:show
ECHO "%desc%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q40986156.txt` containing your data for my testing.

This uses a file as input. Since I don't have access to `perforce`, I can't test it but

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "skip=2tokens=*" %%a IN ('p4 describe -s') DO (
 SET "desc=%%a"
 GOTO show
)

:show
ECHO "%desc%"

GOTO :EOF
```

should be equivalent.

Simply, read the output of the command, skip the first 2 lines, tokenise the entire line, skipping leading spaces. Assign the string found to a variable and immediately exit the loop.

Comment: thanks this answered the question the way I worded, so feels like both answers need to be accepted...